# Windows Server Backup fails because of a FAT32 hidden partition

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

Windows Server 2008 R2.

What shall we do to make the Windows Server Backup to make Full Server backup on our machine that contains an hidden FAT32 partition called OS (size 2GB)?

Why this partition exists? Did the Windows Server 200 R2 setup create it? DELL just confirmed that they didn't create it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just turned on an M600 Blade server from Dell for the first time. There's a 2GB Fat32 parition labelled "OS". This must have been set up at Dell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsbackup/thread/7ff9c298-7e42-4305-ba4c-3273830455d8) on the same issue on the MSDN forums.

Comment: -1; It's not good practise to answer with a link, as your answer will become redundant if the link disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Dell's claim sounds like rubbish to me - are you sure that you were speaking to someone who knew what they (and you) were talking about.

Admittedly the name of the partition sounds a little fishy, but that aside, all Dell servers installed using their server assistant CD will have a hidden "utility partition", which will be FAT32.  Heck, [it's even documented](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pe2650/en/ug/5g387c20.htm#1040825).

I suspect that's what you've encountered, and that the partition name was changed by something like an imaging tool (or do you run a homebrew post-install script to name partitions on your servers?) that just names the first partition "OS" without checking if it actually does contain the OS first.